# jsf array accessing with another variable in the controller

Tags: jsf

How can I access an element in an array were the column is equal to another variable in my controller?

In the contoller I have the array "tab" and the int "mynumber", the variable "i" is just my foreach variable.

Why isn't this working?

```
<h:inputText value="#{controller.tab[i][mynumber]}" /></span>
```

Comment: What is i and mynumber? Are they declared anywhere before?

Comment: i is just a variable of foreach and mynumber is an int in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just write the variable's name. You must use it with the name of the bean that own the variable. So in your situation:

```
<h:inputText value="#{controller.tab[i][controller.mynumber]}" />
```